# C# adding LineBreaks in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I have the problem, that my String is printed correctly in the Console with the LineBreaks, but in the HTML it doesen't show the lineBreaks.
I tried using Environment.LineBreak, "\n", "\r\n" and "
" but nothing seems to work.

````
@{
    var user_height = "";
    var triangle = "";
    if(Request.Method == "POST"){
        user_height = Request.Form["Height"];
        for(int i = 0; i<=Convert.ToInt32(user_height);i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<=i;j++){
                triangle += "*";
            }
            triangle += "\n";
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(triangle);
}

<html>
<head>
<title>Dreiecke und Tannenbaeume</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightgray">
<h1>Dreiecke und Tannenbaeume</h1>

<form action="" method="POST">

<p>Höhe:<br><input size="40" maxlength="3" name="Height"></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Absenden"></p>

</form>

Höhe: @user_height
<div id="dreieck" style="font-family: Courier">
    <h2>Dreieck</h2>
    @triangle
</div>
<div id="tannenbaum" style="font-family: Courier">
    <h2>Tannenbaum</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Do you mean the html tag `<br>` because line breaks as in `\n` are useless for html doesn't care about whitespace characters and they only serve to make things more humanly readable.

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks in HTML are `<br/>`.

Alternatively, you can wrap the output in the `<pre>` tag or add the `white-space: pre;` CSS to the element

Comment: Thanks very much, the pre Tag around the output worked for me!

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your prolem, please mark the answer as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Your `@triangle` is preformatted text, so put it in a `<pre>`:

```
<h2>Dreieck</h2>
    <pre>@triangle</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the pre Tag around the output worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

To create a line break in html, you have to add `<br />` in the code or add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the div `dreieck`.